Angular Signals: How to trigger an effect based on a signal without using its value?
I'm working with Angular and trying to use signals within an effect(). My goal is to trigger an action when a specific signal changes, but the action itself doesn't need the signal's value.
For example, I have an isAuthorized signal, and I want to call fetchCars() whenever the authorization status changes, but fetchCars() doesn't need to use the isAuthorized value.
constructor() {
  effect(() => {
    const isAuthorized = this.authService.userAuthorized();
    
    // This function doesn't use the value of isAuthorized anyway.
    this.fetchCars();
  });
}

It works but it's a bit odd to assign isAuthorized to a constant without actually using it. Is there a more correct or elegant way to achieve this?
Angular Version: 18.0.1

I did exactly that, and added a comment why I called a signal and not use its value.

I couldn't find a better way other than to either use the toObservable() as mentioned by @JSONDerulo or to trigger the signal getter inside the effect().
However you could define a named effect variable in the service that triggers the signal getter so that you don't have to trigger it in every single component that uses the effect.
Try the following
Service
import { Injectable, signal, effect } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
  public readonly userAuthorized = signal(false);
  public readonly userAuthorizedEffect = (callback: () => void) =>
    effect(() => {
      this.userAuthorized();
      callback();
    });

  public toggleAuthStatus(): void {
    this.userAuthorized.set(!this.userAuthorized());
  }
}

Component
export class App {
  constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {
    this.authService.userAuthorizedEffect(() => {
      this.fetchCars();
    });
  }

  fetchCars() {
    console.log('fetching cars here...');
  }
}

Working example: Stackblitz

You can use toObservable() to convert the signal to an Observable:
constructor() {
  toObservable(this.authService.userAuthorized)
    .pipe(takeUntilDestroyed())
    .subscribe(() => this.fetchCars())
}


toObservable is part of the RxJS Interop package
which is currently in developer preview
and might undergo (breaking) changes before becoming stable.


Note: As of this writing, Angular Signal RxJS Interop package is in developer preview.

@MichaelD effect is in developer preview as well, so I thought that shouldn't be an issue. But definitely worth to mention, will add it to the answer. Thanks!

This is how utility frameworks are born. If there is nothing that provides you this functionality for signals, write your own utilities.
E.g. the API could look like this:
// if you want to skip the initial value
effectOnChange([skipFirst(this.authService.userAuthorized)], () => {
    this.fetchCars();
});

// if you only want to run the effect if authorized
effectOnChange([filterSignal(this.authService.userAuthorized, Boolean)], () => {
    this.fetchCars();
});

// if you want the effect on any change
effectOnChange([this.authService.userAuthorized], () => {
    this.fetchCars();
});

And this could be the implementation that hides the complexity from your business logic:
function skipFirst<T>(original: Signal<T>): Signal<T> {
    let init = true;
    const delegate = signal<T>(original());
    effect(
        () => {
            const next = original();
            if (init) {
                init = false;
                return;
            }
            delegate.set(next);
        },
        {allowSignalWrites: true},
    );

    return delegate;
}

function filterSignal<T>(original: Signal<T>, filter: (value: T) => boolean): Signal<T> {
    const delegate = signal<T>(original());
    effect(
        () => {
            const next = original();
            if (filter(next)) {
                delegate.set(next);
            }
        },
        {allowSignalWrites: true},
    );

    return delegate;
}

function effectOnChange(ons: Signal<unknown>[], fn: () => void) {
    let init = true;
    effect(() => {
        ons.forEach((on) => on());
        if (init) {
            init = false;
            return;
        }
        fn();
    });
}


You can accomplish this without assigning a variable to the Signal, and use "untracked()" to skip any additional code from being tracked.
constructor() {
    effect(() => {
        // const isAuthorized = this.authService.userAuthorized();
        this.authService.userAuthorized();
        
        // this.fetchCars();
        untracked(() => {
            this.fetchCars();
        });
    });
}


There have been several discussions about explicit tracking in effects on the Angular GitHub (see here for example), but they have so far refused to reconsider it.
Your situation is one of the consequences of this decision.
Moreover, even though toObservable() is a viable alternative, I find it less explicit than effects that are immediately understood as "a reaction to a signal change".
So you could write your own functions to hide the odd boilerplate (see @sod's answer), but the ngxtension library already provides an explicitEffect function.
In your case, you could use it that way:
explicitEffect([this.authService.userAuthorized()],
  () => this.fetchCars();
);

And it also allows to react to changes in signals defined otherwise (inputs for example).
